# Disabling a drop down and coloring its label based on a Radio Button

Tags: jquery, forms, colors

I have the following, and for some reason I just cant get the drop down to disable or the label to change color.  Basically the only thing that is working is the disabling the text box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input:radio[name=Event-Location]').click(function() {
    var checkval = $(this).val();
    $('#Reservation-Style').prop('disabled', !(checkval == 'City1'));
    $('label[for=Reservation-Style]').css({color:'red'}, !(checkval == 'City1'));
    $('label[for=Reservation-Style]').css({color:'black'}, !(checkval == 'City2'));
    $('#Permits-Needed').prop('disabled', !(checkval === 'City1'));  
    $('#Permits-Needed').prop('enabled', !(checkval === 'City2'));
 });

});
```

And the html looks like:

```
<div id="Event-Location" class="formelement">
  <input type="radio" name="Event-Location" value="City1" />City 1 Campus<br />
  <input type="radio" name="Event-Location" value="City2" />City 2 Campus
</div>

<h3>City 2 Events Only</h3>

<label class="uni-form-text-label" for="Reservation-Style">Reservation Style:</label>
<select name="Reservation-Style" >
  <option>- Style -</option>
  <option value="Permits">Individual Permits</option>
  <option value="Cordon">Cordoned Parking Area</option>
</select>

<label for="Number-Permits-Needed">How Many Permits are needed? </label>
<input id="Number-Permits-Needed" class="text" type="text" name="Number-Permits-Needed" size="15">
```

Comment: To get the select menu you are calling $('#Reservation-Style') which finds the element with the id of Reservation-Style. The html you provided does not have that id anywhere. Your select menu only has a name of Reservation-Style.

Comment: **Thank you!**  I have been staring at this all morning, and I knew it was going to be something idiotic.